# What is this bit of code doing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, numpy, computer-vision

```
  for x, y in [np.int32(tr[-1]) for tr in self.tracks]:
                cv2.circle(mask, (x, y), 5, 0, -1)
            p = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(frame_gray, mask=mask, **feature_params)
            if p is not None:
                for x, y in np.float32(p).reshape(-1, 2):
                    self.tracks.append([(x, y)])
```

I am confused by these for loops, I am quite new to python 3.From what I gather it is first stepping through the x,y values for each tr (from the end? is that what the -1 indicates?)

anyway for each tr in its instance: self.tracks. The bottom for loop is doing the same in the numpy float array:p? Why are they using 'reshape'? What is that doing?

If someone wouldn't mind perhaps just stepping through it for me
I'd greatly appreciate.

Comment: there are some objects that not described in provided sample, so it's hard to understand what's this code about... `[-1]` means index of last element in list. About `numpy` module and it's functions (including `reshape`) you can read here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html

Comment: By using a standalone example with one particular question addressed instead of the general, "what is going on" and after reading through what each of the functions are supposed to do in an api, or checking if something similar has already been asked, I think you could avoid the hail of downvotes. Just to keep in mind for next time.

Comment: Indentation is messed up.  The use of `np.int32` and `np.float32` is unusual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

self.tracks seems to be an (n,2) `list`. The outer loop takes each of these values, turns them two by two into integers `x` and `y`, then performs a function/method `cv2.circle` with an object `mask` and several other parameters. `container[-1]` indicates that you want the value of the last index of `container`.

The values of the function/method `goodFeaturesToTrack` are assigned to `p`(which seem to be an array or `None`). `**` indicates that `feature_params` is a dictionary of parameters(if a function is defined as `myfunc(a,b=2,c=3,d=5)` you could change some of these values for that 
function call by calling `myfunc("value of a",**mydict)` with mydict being a dictionary containing zero or more of the optional variables a, b and c (eg `mydict={'b':8,`d`:0}` would change b and d from their default values to 8 and 0 respectively.

a new (float-valued) `x` and `y` are then extracted from a reshape of p and appended back to the list `self.tracks` as a pair.

The -1 in the reshape indicate that you dont care about how long the given axis as long as the other axis has the right shape. eg. an array of 10 values would be reshaped to (5,2) a (4,4) would be reshaped to (8,2) etc. This could have been found by searching for [`numpy.reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape):

> newshape : int or tuple of ints
>
> The new shape should be compatible with the original shape. If an >integer, then the result will be a 1-D array of that length. One shape >dimension can be -1. In this case, the value is inferred from the length of >the array and remaining dimensions.